# wordpress protected pages

Tags: php, wordpress, protected

I would like to access WordPress protected pages through of a token. The scenario would be: I pass  a token in URL, than check if the requested is a page or not,if yes is the page protected or not, if yes check the URL has the token, if it has check if the token match or not.

**UPDATE**

The workaround what I found and is working in my case

```
    function check_token() {
        if (post_password_required() && (!empty($_GET['token'])) ){
            if($_GET['token'] == 'test'){
             global $post;
                $post->post_password=null;
            }
        }
    }

add_action('wp_head','check_token');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the top of the page template, before the loop:

```
if( get_query_var( 'token' ) == 'xyz' )
    query_posts( 'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'any' ) );
```

I can't find a post a status corresponding to "protected" - protected how? Find the actual post status in the list and replace "any" with it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Here is how to register 'token':

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars[] = 'token';
    return $query_vars;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback .I think this can't work because page protection holds post variables and as I understood I should register first the get variable to get it work in wordpress, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Oh yes! Very well done catching that mistake. I updated my post.